# Urban AirShip and contentful IOS7

Tags: objective-c, urbanairship.com, contentful

Im making an application using the Contentful API the application is working fine. I'm trying to add the UrbanAirship to add notifications.

I add the Contentful headers by using cocoapods so I have a pod directory and all that stuff.

Here is my problem if I add in the Header Search Paths the Urban Airship like this 
`../Airship/**` it recognise the Airship headers but fails to recognise the contentful headers. I have also try adding the headers like this `$(PROJECT_DIR)/Airship`also works but gets me the same error

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figure it out. I just restore the snapshot and add agian the urbanAirship and use the header ./Airship and it works